# Oracle mutating tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, mutating-table

I have this procedure which calculates the total amount paid for a car and determines if the car status can be changed to 'SOLD' if the amount is equal to the price.

I know the problem is the query in car_payment but I can't find other way to make the sum of the amount, can anybody help me, please?

```
create or replace trigger tr_paid_car
    before insert
    or update of amount
    on car_payment
    for each row

declare 
    v_amount number;
    v_car_status_id car_status.car_status_id%type;
    v_price car.price%type;
begin
    select sum(amount)
        into v_amount
        from car_payment
        where car_id = :new.car_id;

    if inserting then 
        v_amount := v_amount + :new.amount;
    elsif updating then
        v_amount := v_amount + :new.amount - :old.amount;
    end if;

    select price
        into v_price
        from car
        where car_id = :new.car_id;

    if v_amount >= v_price then
        select car_status_id
        into v_car_status_id
        from car_status
        where description = 'SOLD';

        update car
            set car_status_id = v_car_status_id
            where car_id = :new.car_id;
    end if;
end;
```

/

Comment: If you must use triggers in your calculations and trigger the same table that is being queried then probably your best bet is PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION to avoid mutating table error.

Comment: Seriously consider NOT using triggers to enforce application logic.  The application should call a PL/SQL API to report a car as "sold".  That API should check whether the payment amount is equal to the price and return a failure to its caller if not equal.

Comment: I second the comment by @MatthewMcPeak. Take this code out of the trigger. Build a package with insert and update procs. Grant execute on the package to your devs and users, but do not allow direct DML on the table. Then put this logic in the procedures and you are golden.

Answer (score 0):

Create a another function called: GET_CAR_PAY_AMT  as below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_CAR_PAY_AMT(p_car_id car_payment.car_id%type) return number
as
pragma autonomous_transaction;
x number;
begin
select sum(amount)
        into x
        from car_payment
        where car_id = p_car_id;
return x;
end GET_CAR_PAY_AMT;
```

Now use function GET_CAR_PAY_AMT instead of your SELECT statement in the trigger as below:

Replace below SQL:

```
select sum(amount)
into v_amount
from car_payment
where car_id = :new.car_id;
```

With:

```
v_amount := GET_CAR_PAY_AMT(:new.car_id);
```

Comment: I'd say not. The fact that you moved SELECT into a function means nothing, it'll still raise the *mutating table* error.

Comment: is it, i will it again.

Comment: I have updated the answer with Adding "PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION" in function and tested it on my site, now it's not throwing any mutating error.